# Page.user.identity.name return trust relationship failed

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page, previously is working fine, but 3 days ago hit an error. Some time can access but certain time cannot.

It hit error on aspx.cs when call 'page.user.identity.name' and return error 'the trust relationship between this a
workstation and the primary domain failed'

```
public partial class LoginPage : System.Web.UI.Page { 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
        string strUserIdentity = string.Empty; 
        try { 
            strUserIdentity = Convert.ToString(Page.User.Identity.Name);
            Response.Write("<br>name = " + Page.User.Identity.Name);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { 
            Response.Write("<script>window.alert('[Error message:" + ex.Message + "].Please contact System Administrator for assistance.')</script>");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: iis use window authentication

Comment: Edit the code ***into the question*** not the comments